# `let` vs. `const` vs. nothing in a for–of loop

Tags: javascript, variables, for-of-loop

What is the difference in doing the following three constructions in JavaScript:

```js
let dd = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];

for(const item of dd) console.log(item);
for(let   item of dd) console.log(item);
for(      item of dd) console.log(item);
```

It seems they all produce the exact same results so wondering if there are some subtle differences between them, especially when neither `let` nor `const` is there, specifically in the context for a `for`–`of` loop.

Comment: Also, you're not mutating the value in this example in any case...

Comment: @msanford what happens in the third case where neither `let` nor `const` is there?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Use strict mode and the error will tell you what happen :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some examples that demonstrate the difference:

```js
let dd = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// identically-named variable in the outer scope
let item = -1

for (const item of dd) {
    console.log(item) // ok
    // console.log(++item) // can't re-assign - will throw if uncommented
}

console.log(item) // still -1, as `const` is block-scoped

for (let item of dd) {
    console.log(item) // ok
    console.log(++item) // it's fine to re-assign 
}

console.log(item) // still -1, as `let` is block-scoped

for (item of dd) {}

console.log(item) // 5, as we've now re-assigned the variable in the outer scope
// due to not using `const` or `let`
```